# Calculator for real and complex parts of a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, online-resources, calculator

Does anyone know of a nice calculator for calculating the real and complex parts of a complex polynomial.  Say, for example, I want to write the polynomial $p(z)=z^3+2z^2+1$ as a function $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$, but I do not want to calculate $f_1$ and $f_2$ by hand.

Comment: You can just use the binomial theorem to separate real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Wolfram Alpha.  [Example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=imaginary%20part%20of%20%28%28x%2biy%29%5E4%20-%202%28x%2biy%29%5E2%29).

Comment: Or write it [this way](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+z%5E3%2B2z%5E2%2B1+where+z%3Dx%2Biy&x=0&y=0).

Comment: Thanks, I have almost no experience with doing math on computers, so that was very helpful.